# Vue keeping specific component alive under router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my home page I have two components. I want only one to be kept alive.

HomeView.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <keep-alive>
       <AliveComponent />
    </keep-alive>
    <DeadComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

In my App.vue I have kept the `<router-view />` alive as well

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <main>
    <keep-alive include="HomeView">
      <router-view />
    </keep-alive>
  </main>
  <Footer />
</template>
```

The problem is the `<keep-alive include="HomeView">` is keeping both components alive. I tried to replace it with `include="AliveComponent"` but turns out nothing is alive.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The second approach seems fine, don't now why it is causing error. However, try this-

Comment: Remove the keep-alive from Homeview.vue, keep it only in App.vue, and in App.vue use this syntax.

`<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive include="AliveComponent">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>`

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your components have a valid name that you are planning to use in `keep-alive`. This could be an issue if you did not provide a name to your "AliveComponent" because the `include` property matches the component name.**

I produced a demo here in which I create two routes. Each route has a component and each component has its state. When changing any component's state and switching to another route, the component which is included in the `keep-alive` will have preserved state while others will not.

```js
// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
const AliveC = {
name: "AliveComponent",
template: `<div>
    <button @click="count = count + 1">Increase Alive Count</button>
    <h3>Alive Component Count - {{ count }}</h3>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
 }
 
const DeadC = { 
name: "DeadComponent",
template: `<div>
    <button @click="count = count + 1">Increase Dead Count</button>
    <h3>Dead Component Count - {{ count }}</h3>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
}

// 2. Define some routes
// Each route should map to a component.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: AliveC },
  { path: '/dead', component: DeadC },
]

// 3. Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  // 4. Provide the history implementation to use. We are using the hash history for simplicity here.
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 5. Create and mount the root instance.
const app = Vue.createApp({})
// Make sure to _use_ the router instance to make the
// whole app router-aware.
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')

// Now the app has started!
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <router-link to="/">Switch To Alive Component Route</router-link>&ensp;&ensp;
    <router-link to="/dead">Switch To Dead component Route</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive include="AliveComponent">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for not mentioning I am using vue2. In my case, both alive component and dead component are wrapped in HomeView. I was able to keeep a whole page alive instead of keeping one component only.